# Path issue with AJAX

Tags: php, html, ajax

Alright so I have 2 folders. This is how my layout looks on my server right now.

folders:

- Ajax/
- Processor/

Files:

- Login.php
- Carelogin.php

Originally I did NOT have a processor folder. So I had my login.php file right under my carelogin.php and everything worked just fine.

Now since I put my login.php file into the processor folder and changed the path in my functions.js in my ajax folder everything is all messed up.

This is my ajax functions.

```
$(function() {
      $("#submit_login").click(function() {
        var username = $("input#username").val();
        if (username == "") {
           $('.errormess').html('Please Insert Your Username'); 
           return false;
        }
        var password = $("input#password").val();
        if (password == "") {
           $('.errormess').html('Please Insert Your Password'); 
           return false;
        }


        var dataString = 'username='+ username + '&password=' + password;
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: '/processor/login.php',
          data: dataString,
          dataType: "html",
          success: function(data) {
          if (data == 0) {
          $('.errormess').html('Invalid username/password combination');
            } else {
                $('.errormess').html('<b style="color:green;">Thanks for loggin in</b>');   
                document.location.href = 'home.php';    
            }
          }
         });
        return false;
        });
    });
```

As you can see I have it pointed to the /processor/login.php and it is not working anymore. Just keeps logging me in like its not even checking the login.php file anymore. Even with the wrong creds I can still log in now.

When I had that url just pointed to login.php it all worked perfect.

this is my carelogin.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>

      <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/pagecss/logincss.css" />
          <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax/jquery.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax/functions.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='container'>
        <img src='images/tigger.png' class='logo'/>
          <div class="login_form">
                <form method="POST" action="/processor/login.php">

    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" /><br />

    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" /><br />
    <input type="submit" id="submit_login" name="submit" class="inputbutton grey" value="Login" />
    <span class="login_loading"></span>
    <span class="errormess"></span>
    </form>
            <p class='version'>Version 1.6.1119.15 </p>
         </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

finally, here is my login.php file

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require 'connect.php';
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo 'Failed to Connect to MySQL' . mysqli_connect_errno();
    }
    if (isset($_POST)) { 
      $user = $_POST['username'];
      $pass =  md5($_POST['password']);
      $query = mysqli_query($conns, "SELECT * FROM tech WHERE username = '$user' and password = '$pass'") or die("Can not query the DB");
      $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
      if($count == 1) {
      $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
        echo $user;
      }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Change `/processor/login.php` to `processor/login.php` and **SQL injection alert!**

Comment: tried it like that aswell, Not working.

Comment: @ShlomiHassid You messed up my question when you edited it, wtf.

Answer (score 0):

I see in your folder list:

```
'Processor'
```

while in your ajax call your url points to:

```
'/processor/login.php'
```

Keep in mind that PHP is case sensitive

If your ajax cal is in the 'Ajax folder' you maybe need to do:

```
'../processor/login.php'
```

Comment: I just typed it wrong in here. It is not in caps in my folder.

Comment: @Kmiles1990123 I have updated my answer. Try it if your ajax call is in the 'Ajax' folder. Otherwise ignore it. I am just trying to help you out!

Comment: Nope that didn't work either. I'm so confused why it's not. So weird.

Comment: Can you tell me the exact location of your ajax function? I suppose your connection with the database is not giving you any error!

Comment: my function.js is located in my ajax folder. and no, no DB errors.

Comment: I don't follow anymore. This is strange. This should be work ''../processor/login.php''. I would like to help you out but unfortunately here is 2:30 a.m. so I go to rest. I will look tomorrow to know why this is not working and if you have found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

add:

```
else{
 echo $count;
}
```

after:

```
if($count == 1) {
   $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
   echo $user;
}
```

your ajax condition will always execute the else statement because the value that returns to your ajax is the user's username.

also edit this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax/functions.js"></script>
```

to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../ajax/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../ajax/functions.js"></script>
```

Comment: Alert the data that was returned to your ajax and post it here.